# Reading an XML file with PHP5

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

So i've been trying to get some data from a PlaystationNetwork API,

http://www.psnapi.com.ar/ps3/api/psn.asmx/getPSNID?sPSNID=jameslfc19

So I've been using this code

```
<?php
//Get Username
$username = $_GET["u"];

// Passing the XML
$psnxml = @simplexml_load_file('http://psnapi.com.ar/ps3/api/psn.asmx/getPSNID?sPSNID=' .$username);

$psnname = $psnxml->PSNId->Avatar;
echo $psnname;
?>
```

This outputs absolutely nothing..

I'm using @ because otherwise I get a (Yes i know, but I thought it would still be getting the data even though the XML doc has a 500 Internel Server Error)

```
Warning: simplexml_load_file(http://psnapi.com.ar/ps3/api/psn.asmx/getPSNID?sPSNID=jameslfc19) [function.simplexml-load-file]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Sigs/PSN2.php on line 6
```

What is the best way to do this? I'm assuming that the error im ignoring with @ is causing the problem.

Comment: "500 Internal Server error" is on psnapi.com.ar's side. It's the root of your problem.

Comment: So... you're suppressing the warning and are wondering why nothing's happening...?

Comment: I see, so how should I fix this? Using cURL? I have never used cURL before.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still learning a lot about PHP, I knew it'd be a bad idea posting here. I'll look else where.

Comment: @jameslfc19 the problem is not with your PHP knowledge, rather your common sense. How would you be supposed to fix the error which you didn't cause?

Comment: I was reading from this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436614/internal-server-error-500-simplexml-load-file Tried a lot of things, using @ was the one that didn't give me an error. I think we've established it was a bit stupid to use @, Can you suggest what I should do instead?

Comment: @jameslfc19 if the server that you're trying to contact is not accessible, then you can't do much.

Comment: @jameslfc19 as if StackOverflow was down and you were trying to fix that you're not able to post questions or alike...

Comment: The thing is, You can still read the document in a browser http://www.psnapi.com.ar/ps3/api/psn.asmx/getPSNID?sPSNID=jameslfc19

Comment: So will it be better to just try and find a better API?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think `simplexml_load_file` is intended to read local files, not ressources from a URL?

Comment: I think you can, at least here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436614/internal-server-error-500-simplexml-load-file nobody mentions `simplexml_load_file` not being able to read resources from a URL.

Comment: Alright, then it should be possible. I added an answer with what I fount on php.net regarding this or at least a similar problem.

Comment: Thank you! I can't upvote because I don't have 15 rep yet.

Comment: First see, whether it helps or not. In case it does, you can "accept" it.

Comment: Your'e welcome! And don't be shy to ask ("Sorry, I'm still learning a lot about PHP, I knew it'd be a bad idea posting here. I'll look else where.")! As long as you show some effort to solve your problem every question is welcome. :-)

Comment: Ok :) Thanks, A lot of time I make silly mistakes, so I dont usually like asking. But thanks again! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the comments on `simlexml_load_file` [on php.net](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php) I found the following. Not tested, but worth a try.

> sean at aliencreations dot com 17-Mar-2011 10:59 If you find that you
>   are receiving 500 errors with simplexml_load_file() but you can access
>   the xml/rss feed manually through a browser, your script is probably
>   being blocked by a user agent sniffer.
>
> Add this code before your xml call to remedy this issue
>
> ```
> <?php
>
> ini_set("user_agent","Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)");
> ini_set("max_execution_time", 0);
> ini_set("memory_limit", "10000M");
>
> $rss = simplexml_load_file($feed_url);
>
> ?>
> ```

Comment: Thank you! I can't upvote because I dont have enough reputation. But thank you very much!